# Beam/Dataflow - Big CoGroupByKey results cause slow pipeline

Tags: parallel-processing, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have 2 `PCollection<KV<String, String>>`, one is of size ~150M and the second is ~2B.

What I want to do is to count the number of appearance of each unique value pairs from both `PCollection`.

So I did a `CoGroupByKey` on these 2 PCollections, the problem is that some (~5M) of the `CoGbkResult` are very big (I get log messages in Dataflow saying `CoGbkResult` has more than 10K results) since in both collections each key can appear many times and this causes very long runtimes in the workers that get these keys.

Ideally I'd like the `CoGroupByKey` to return a `PCollection` that contains all the pairs of values from both `PCollection` co grouped by the key, so I cant count them in a way the parallelizes better.

I have been reading about this problem but there doesnt seem to be a solution that fits me (most of which include using a `Combine.WithHotKeyFanout`) since I need an extra step of mapping before combining which takes forever because of the size of the `CoGbkResult`.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what kind of operation you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to reformat your data so that you can replace `CoGroupByKey` with `CombinePerKey`?

`CoGroupByKey` & `GroupByKey` are building lists of all the matches as they go which can get really big, but you only care about the count right? So you could use `CombinePerKey` with a `CombineFn` that counts them as they come in

Reformat your PCollections from something like this:

```
pcoll_a = [('abc','123'), ('abc', '456'), ...]
pcoll_b = [('abc','123'), ('xyz', '456'), ...]
```

Into something like this:

```
pcoll_a = [('abc,123', 'A'), ('abc,456', 'A'), ...]
pcoll_b = [('abc,123', 'B'), ('xyz,456', 'B'), ...]
```

Flatten these 2 PCollections together:

```
pcoll_combined = [('abc,123', 'A'), ('abc,456', 'A'), ('abc,123', 'B'), ('xyz,456', 'B'), ...]
```

Pass this into `CombinePerKey` with a `CombineFn` that is summing up the count as you go. Something like this:

```
class CountFn(apache_beam.core.CombineFn):
    def _add_inputs(self, elements, accumulator=None):
        accumulator = accumulator or self.create_accumulator()
        for obj in elements:
            if obj == 'A':
                accumulator['sum_A'] += 1
            if obj == 'B':
                accumulator['sum_B'] += 1
        return accumulator

    def create_accumulator(self):
        return {'sum_A': 0, 'sum_B': 0}

    def add_input(self, accumulator, element, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._add_inputs(elements=[element], accumulator=accumulator)

    def add_inputs(self, accumulator, elements, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._add_inputs(elements=elements, accumulator=accumulator)

    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators, *args, **kwargs):
        return {
            'sum_A': sum([i['sum_A'] for i in accumulators]),
            'sum_B': sum([i['sum_B'] for i in accumulators])}

    def extract_output(self, accumulator, *args, **kwargs):
        return accumulator
```